# how to find address of a place or latitude longitude of a place from an IP address using google api

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

how to find address of a place or latitude longitude of a place from an IP address using google api . I need to implement radius search , for that i need latitude longitude of  user current location , for that how i will get , because if user does not selectes  browsers share location option , then i have only one way to get lat long using its IP address . But for that i need a service from which i can get this . Does ggogle provide this service to get lat long from IP address then please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party tool [ipinfo](http://ipinfo.io) to get location

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8
{
  "ip": "8.8.8.8",
  "hostname": "google-public-dns-a.google.com",
  "loc": "37.385999999999996,-122.0838",
  "org": "AS15169 Google Inc.",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "CA",
  "country": "US",
  "phone": 650
}
```

Comment: You can also get more options here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698483/what-is-the-way-to-get-exact-geolocation-of-remote-machine-in-php-html5

Comment: does google provides any such service/api from which we can gather  latitude, longitude from an IP address . Or is there any way or free service available for  this requirement

Answer (score 0):

Actually, yes, there is a service to get lat long from IP address using the device-scpecific [Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation).

However, there are given consequences that you must consider wherein some browser/devices support it, while others do not (or cannot), so you cannot assume that geolocation is always possible for a web application. And as also mentioned in detecting the user's location:

> Some browsers use IP addresses to detect a user's location. However, as a user's IP address can only provide a rough estimate of a user's location, we don't recommend using this approach for geolocation. The W3C approach is the easiest and most fully-supported so it should be prioritized over other methods.

Aside from that, it was also stated in [W3C Geolocation API Specification](https://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) that:

> The Geolocation API defines a high-level interface to location information associated only with the device hosting the implementation, such as latitude and longitude.
>
> No guarantee is given that the API returns the device's actual location.

For additional queries regarding Geolocation API, answers can be found in this article [Where is Geolocation of an IP Address?](https://www.iplocation.net/) and in [Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) documentation.